# ImportError: No module named applicationform.wsgi

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, deployment

I'm deploying an app in AWS, when I run `gunicorn` in a virtual env to test if it works correctly I'm getting the error message below:

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-232:~/applicationform/newProject$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 applicationform.wsgi:application
[2018-08-09 00:52:20 +0000] [22973] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-08-09 00:52:20 +0000] [22973] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (22973)
[2018-08-09 00:52:20 +0000] [22973] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-08-09 00:52:20 +0000] [22977] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22977
[2018-08-09 00:52:20 +0000] [22977] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/applicationform/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/applicationform/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/applicationform/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/applicationform/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/applicationform/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/applicationform/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/applicationform/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named applicationform.wsgi
[2018-08-09 00:52:20 +0000] [22977] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22977)
[2018-08-09 00:52:20 +0000] [22973] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-08-09 00:52:20 +0000] [22973] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Testing the app on AWS I also get the internal server error.

The code is on Github https://github.com/sannicko/applicationform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `applicationform.wsgi: application` in your command line actually tells `gunicorn` to run the function named `application()` in the Python module `applicationform/wsgi.py`. In your case there is no `applicationform` directory under your working directory, which is `~/applicationform/newProject`.

You should run it from the `~/applicationform` directory and the app name would then be `newProject.wsgi`, i.e.:

```
~/applicationform$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 newProject.wsgi:application
```